# Connect to Hadoop by using Java using unix Sudo and SSH

Tags: java, unix, hadoop, ssh

I am trying to connect to Hadoop using Java program. First of all let me tell you that I am new to Java, but I am able to understand basic code.

This is how I use to connect to Hadoop (on Unix) through Putty:

1. Connect to Unix (By giving Host Name, User Name and Password)
2. Run sudo command (sudo su -xxx) (I will have to provide my password here)
3. Run SSH Command from current host to Hadoop host (ssh abcdefgh)

Using a Java program, I was able to connect to Unix (Step 1). Even I can run one Unix command in the directory I have connected to. Like `ls`, `wc-l` etc.

But I still have to give one more time password using `sudo` command (Step 2). After that, I run ssh command (Step 3)

Can somebody help me with the remaining steps? If I have to import any jar files, please help me with the links also. I am providing my current unix connecting Java program below. I downloaded Jar file `com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.31` for my Java program.

```js
package com.abc;

import java.io.InputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo;

public class First 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String user="User ID";
        String host="host Name";
        String cmd="ls";
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        
        try
        {
            Session session=jsch.getSession(user,host,22);
            session.setPassword("pwd"); 
            UserInfo usrInfo=new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(usrInfo);
            session.connect();
            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
            
            System.out.println("*** 1 ***");
            
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(cmd);
            channel.setXForwarding(true);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("*** 2 ***");
                
                while (in.available() > 0)
                {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                    System.out.println("*** 3 ***");
                }

                if (channel.isClosed())
                {
                    in.close();
                    break;
                }
                
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception ee) {}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception"+e);
        }
    }

    public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo 
    {
        public String getPassword() { return "password"; }
        public String getPassphrase() { return ""; }
        public boolean promptPassword(String arg0) { return true; }
        public boolean promptPassphrase(String arg0) { return true; }
        public boolean promptYesNo(String arg0) { return true; }
        public void showMessage(String arg0) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you're going to be able to provide a password to sudo from your program, for security reasons `sudo` requires the password be entered directly or you configure `sudo` to not prompt for a password at all.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sudo has a command-line option to read the password from standard input.

Comment: @Kenster Why did you reply to my comment instead of posting an answer?